# In angularjs application, html pages display even though a user is not logged in

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angularJS application which requires logging in. I have defined my states in the application. If I don't log in and directly open a state in the browser it redirects to 404.

The issue is when I explicitly open a .html page in browser without logging in, it shows me the HTML elements and non-rendered angularJS expressions. In the network tab of developer tools, the Status Code is 200. How do I get 404 instead and the same to redirect to 404 or login page?

My application is hosted on Apache Tomcat.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

The following is an example: (I can't provide code though).

Let's say I have a folder client with ClientView.html as the view in the folder. The following would be the route in my app.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider
    .state('app.client', {
    // child state of `app`                       
    url: '/client',
    views: {
        'content@app': {
            templateUrl: 'client/ClientView.html',
            controller: 'ClientCtrl'
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true
        }
    }
})
```

});

If I access the application as http://localhost/app/client without logging in, this does take me to 404.

But if I try to access http://localhost/app/client/ClientView.html then it shows me the html elements in that page as well as non-rendered AngularJs expressions. How do I redirect to login page or 404?

Comment: Provide some code. So that we can help.

Comment: Put a condition on your respective controllers and check the session .. if it is invalid redirect to 404 view. This is my approach to  this problem may have better approach

Comment: @Sai I have updated the question. I can't provide code though.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma I have updated the question and provided an example. I did try that and that works for the states and not when you give explicit html URLs in browser.

Comment: @pix1289 It looks like you have not authenticated all your html resources in server.

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor can you please elaborate ?

Comment: use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/client") to redirect to 404. and specify the route for all other required page. for example: if login home page url: '/home', @pix1289

Comment: @pix1289 Is ClientView.html a template?

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor yes.

Comment: @pix1289 I think I misunderstood your problem. If the file is a template, then the angularjs will not be loaded and hence you will not be able to do anything to 'ensure security' using the client side. Usually,if my app is secured using cookies, I will secure all the resources instead of just the main page from server. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor yes it does. So how do I ensure security then? Can web.xml be useful in this scenario?

Comment: @pix1289 That depends, which language are you using? You might be securing the 'base_url/index.html', but what you really meant is 'base_url/**/*'.

Comment: @pix1289 In your case, you might be securing `http://localhost/app/client` (as it shows a 404 error), but you need to secure `http://localhost/app/client/**`.

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor hmm yea. Need to figure out though how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is how I handled it currently. If login is successful, I have created and set sessionStorage variable to true. In every HTML page in my application, I have added a short script, checking the above flag. If it's not set then I redirect to 404 page.

This is clearly not the right way to do it and has redundacy. If anyone else has a better approach, kindly let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable `isAppLog = true` when user logs in. And check for login or not using:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState  , toParams, fromState, fromParams)
{
    if(toState.data.requireLogin=== true && !$rootScope.isAppLog ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

This checks for whether user loggedin or not and if not redirects to login page.

Comment: I will try this.Thank you. This will work for routes defined I know, but will they for  URLs like these http://localhost/app/client/ClientView.html?

Comment: what I mean is in AngularJS applications, we will go from one state to another using the predefined routes in our app.js. The way you have in your code: $state.go('login'). You have defined this as route and what template to load and what controller it will use. What I am saying though is: instead of putting the route in the browser as /login; try putting /login/LoginView.html. (assuming here login is a folder and LoginView.html is the template for it inside the same folder)

Comment: We use predefined routes in angularjs. You can specify those folders or something in `templateUrl`.